# How can I retrieve instances of a monthly recurring event using Google Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I tried many ways and I am able to retrieve all instances of different types of events using the API, but I could not find any way to retrieve instances of monthly recurring events. I'll appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the instances call to retrieve all (or a subset of instances) of a given event:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances

You will need to know the ID of the recurring event though.

Comment: Hey luc, Unfortunately it only returns the first occurrence of a monthly recurring event. Not the rest of them. E.g. try to create an event Monthly on the second Friday, until Dec 12, 2014, and test what happens.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce this. I created an event as you described, got it through the calendar explorer with no problem (GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/<eid>/instances). Are you sure you are using the correct id for the <eid> part? It needs to be the one that has no underscore.